# How to avoid opening other android stores and open only Google Play Store on Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

In many Mi phones, when I use this code to open the Google play store, the MI store opens.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
```

How do I avoid that and check if the Google play store is installed and open only the Google play store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `Intent`'s package to `com.android.vending`, which is the package name of the Play Store app.  This will make it so that only that app will receive the Intent.

Based on [Linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app):

Kotlin:

```kotlin
val appPackageName = "your.package.name.here"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse(
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")
    setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

Java:

```java
String appPackageName = "your.package.name.here";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

If the Play Store is not installed, the `startActivity` call will throw an [`ActivityNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException), which you can catch.

I believe this would also work with the `market://` URLs, but I haven't tested that since I don't have a Mi phone to confirm.